# Creating a Simple ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone

I am new to Windows Phone development and i want to create a simple ListBox.

I have an Array with 10 Names which i want to display in a list Box.

```
string[] names = new string[10] {"Matt", "Joanne", "Robert", .........};
```

Now i want to use this Array to feed the listBox dynamically and show it.
[image]

Can someone help me with an Example on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the array as the ItemSource for the ListBox:

```
listBox.ItemSource = names;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Windows Phone development, but in winforms it'd be `listbox.Items.AddRange(names);`